# Blending between an N-sided shape and a perfect circle with the same origin?

Tags: python, 3d

I'm currently writing a 3D shader for a computer program, and I've run into a bit of a problem I'm hoping someone can help me with.

The shader is designed to generate an N-sided shape in 2D space. The 3D program that drives the shader essentially passes you a set of x, y coordinates (centred around 0, 0) and expects you to output the appropriate colour. I've already written the portion of the shader that generates these shapes, which works well enough. What I'm having problems with is adding "curvature" to the sides of these shapes, essentially blending between a perfect circle and an N-sided polygon.

The way the shader currently works is as follows:

1) I figure out the angle of a single segment of the N-sided shape:

```
segmentAngle = (math.pi * 2) / numberOfSides
```

1) I break down the problem into a single right angle triangle, which uses the following equations:

```
pAngle = abs((math.atan2(y, x) % segmentAngle) - (segmentAngle / 2))
pDist1 = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))
```

2) I calculate the distance from the origin of the N-sided shape to the edge, traversing through the coordinates the shader has been given:

```
pDist2 = (math.cos(segmentAngle / 2) * radius) / math.cos(pAngle)
```

where radius is typically 0.5. Then, if pDist1 is > pDist2, the shader returns one colour, otherwise it returns another. This allows me to successfully draw N-sided shapes with any number of sides.

Here's where things get tricky... I also need an option that "blends" between the N-sided shape and a perfect circle (which has the same radius as the N-sided shape). Originally I thought I could do this by simply modifying pDist2 as follows:

```
pDist2 = ((radius - pDist2) * curvature) + pDist2)
```

where curvature is a value between 0 and 1 (representing 0% to 100%). This doesn't work at all, instead I get a weird wavy edge which I believe has something to do with my angles and the difference between pDist2 and the radius of a circle. In theory, it should work assuming pAngle is pointing at the exact centre of one side of the polygon, but as it approaches a corner things seem to get more and more distorted.

How can I fix this? It seems like there should be some reasonably simple formula for correcting pDist2 based on the difference between pAngle and (segmentAngle / 2), but I can't seem to figure out what that should be.

Diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, but you'll have to change the test to something other than `pDist1 > pDist2`:

```
segmentAngle = (math.pi * 2) / numberOfSides
pRawAngle = math.atan2(y, x)
pAngle = abs((pRawAngle % segmentAngle) - (segmentAngle / 2))
pEdgeAngle = pRawAngle - pAngle
pDistanceToEdge = radius * (math.cos(segmentAngle / 2) * radius)
pEdgeVectorX = math.cos(pEdgeAngle)
pEdgeVectorY = math.sin(pEdgeAngle)
pEdgeDot = (x * edgeVectorX) + (y * edgeVectorY)

if pEdgeDot > pDistanceToEdge:        
    pOutsideDistance = pEdgeDot - pDistanceToEdge
    x -= pEdgeVectorX * pOutsideDistance
    y -= pEdgeVectorY * pOutsideDistance
    if curvature > 0:
        pOutsideDistance /= curvature
    x += pEdgeVectorX * pOutsideDistance
    y += pEdgeVectorY * pOutsideDistance

pDist1 = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))

if pDist1 > radius:
    # color one color
else
    # color the other color
```

This code expands each edge of an N-sided polygon into a circle in the direction of the normal to the edge. The edge angle of the closest edge is calculated and used to compute the distance to the center of the edge from the origin (the radius is taken to be measured to the corners of the polygon) and a normal vector.

Then the dot product of the x,y point and the edge normal is taken to see if it is outside the polygon. If it is, then it calculates how far outside it is and then adjusts that amount based on the curvature, in the direction of the edge normal. Then it does a point to radius test with the adjusted point.

Another approach is to use your initial equations but change the calculation of pDist2 like this:

```
segmentAngle = (math.pi * 2) / numberOfSides
pAngle = abs((math.atan2(y, x) % segmentAngle) - (segmentAngle / 2))
pDist1 = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))
if curvature < 1.0:
    pCurvatureAdjustment = (1 / (1.0 - curvature)) - 1.0
    pDist2 = ((math.cos(segmentAngle / 2) + pCurvatureAdjustment) * radius) / (math.cos(pAngle) + pCurvatureAdjustment)
else
    pDist2 = radius
```

Hopefully this should allow the gradient coloring you are after.

If you specifically want a linear blend between the polygon and the circle in the direction of the edge normals, a more accurate calculation is

```
pCurvatureAdjustment = ((1 / (1.0 - curvature)) - 1.0) * math.cos(pAngle)
```

Comment: I hope this works for you in Python, I actually got it going with a jsFiddle. Great question BTW, I initially couldn't believe that your existing code wouldn't work until I tested it for myself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems to do something, but not quite what I'm looking for, probably because I haven't fully explained how the shader is supposed to work (sorry, I was trying to keep things simple). The input is always an x, y set of coordinates, but the output is based on a gradient input (where the origin is always the left most side of the gradient, and the edges are the right most side). This is why pDist1 and pDist2 were calculated the way they are- so I can derive a ratio and use that to determine what colour to return from the gradient. (cont...)

Comment: (Continued) Here's a bunch of pictures from the actual shader. At the moment, it's set to 3 sides and the gradient goes from black (0.6) to white (0.7) to black (0.8), just to get a nice shape for emphasis (if it was a straight linear gradient from black to white, you'd see black in the centre, fading out to white around the edges). http://i.imgur.com/i5S3WUX.jpg (cont...)

Comment: (Continued) Here's what it my old equations look like with the curvature set to 30%. http://i.imgur.com/4JBLWbN.jpg You can clearly see how the edges aren't perfectly circular. And then 100% (which works fine, since that's just a perfect circle). http://i.imgur.com/ghj19ij.jpg Again, sorry for the confusion. I just thought it'd be easier to ignore the whole gradient to try and simplify the question.

Comment: @CMPXCHG8B Ok, no problem. I think that the code can be rearranged to give the outputs you want, but I'll have to come back to it in a few hours

Comment: No problem. It seems to kinda do what I'm looking for, so it's definitely put me on a different track that I will continue to explore further. Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: That last one works perfectly, and is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks for your help!